# How do I position three different elements next to each other in HTML/JS (ideally without float property)?

Tags: html, css

I am currently working on a clicker game (played in-browser) and am having issues placing three elements next to each other. I do cross-reference a JavaScript file within my code, so I will also accept JavaScript answers because it might be simpler through JavaScript. I'm pretty new to coding so please try to keep things simple, but it's fine if there's no simple solution.

I will include a chunk of code below to illustrate what I did, but my idea was to put all three elements (two SVG rectangles, and one PNG img) into a <div> container and use the style="display: inline" attribute to hopefully put them all next to each other, but rather it put the two rectangles next to each other (the pair floating a little more rightward than I'd prefer) and the PNG was somewhere near the bottom of the page.

```
<div style="display: inline; width: 0%">
            <div style="display: inline-block; width: 0%">
            <svg class="fry" width="2000" height="2000">
                <svg x="50" y="50">
                <rect style="background-color:#DAA520" x="0" y="0" width="300"                     height="600" rx="15" stroke="black" stoke-width="25" fill="#DAA520" />
                </svg>
            </svg>
            </div>

            <div x="1000" y="1000" style="display: inline-block">
                <img src="images/frenchfry.png">
            </div>
            
            <div style="display: inline-block; width: 0%">
            <svg class="store" width="2000" height="2000">
                <svg x="1150" y="50">
                <rect style="background-color:#DAA520" x="0" y="0" width="300" height="600" rx="15" stroke="black" stoke-width="25" fill="#DAA520" />
                </svg>
                        </svg>
            </div>

        </div>
```

Comment: That you even mention `float` means you should read a [guide to CSS layout written in the last decade](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout).

Comment: watch a `flexbox` course on youtube, that helps you ... for more positioning skills you can check `grid` tutorial videos too...@Nether-Knight61

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure that's what you are looking for, but u can style it using css.
If you want to position your elements next to each other then try this: (Put style in head section)

```
<style>
    .container{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: 'space-around';
        align-items: 'center';
    }
</style>
```

Try to place all the three elements, that you want to put next to each other, into one div then ad

```
<div class="container">
    // Elements you want to put next to each other
</div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok so the new formatting helped a little, but now the PNG is right next to the rectangle on the left side and the rightward rectangle is just way out left. It’s progress though, and I feel like I’m just gonna have to tinker with some numbers at this point, so thanks, but if you have other suggestions I’m all ears!